# Creating and storing objects in a container without using new?

Tags: c++, loops, object, pointers, instance

Say I have the class

```
class A{
   int value;
public:
   A(int val) : value(val) {};
}
```

I store pointers of instances in a collection such as vector using for loop

```
std::vector<A*> myCollection;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
   myCollection.push_back(&A(i));
}
```

Now the for loop will construct and destruct an object at the same memory location resulting in a vector with 10 pointers pointing to the same address and dereferencing them will give A->value = 9.
Is there any way around this without dynamic allocation? And yes I have to use collection of pointers and not references.

Comment: You could make an array of 10 `A` and put a pointer to each element into the vector

Comment: `&A(i)` should not compile. You should just be using `std::vector<A>` instead of `std::vector<A*>` and then it is simply `myCollection.push_back(A(i));` or `myCollection.emplace_back(i);`/`myCollection.push_back(i);`. What reason do you have to store pointers instead of the objects themselves?

Comment: ```&A(i)``` what are you trying to do with this?

Comment: FYI you won't be able to use references here either.

Comment: Where do you want the objects to be stored? This code does not store them in a container - it only stores pointers to them in a container.

Comment: Unless you need polymorphism for the stored classes you probably shouldn't use pointers in a vector. And when you do then consider smart pointers and `make_shared`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Note OP wrote: *"without dynamic allocation"* so smart pointers are out of the picture for the given question.

Comment: @AnoopRana I hope that is a XY problem and not really a requirement.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I think it is clear(at least to me) that it is a requirement. Although the question could have been more clearly described.

Answer (score 1):

If the objects need to be on the stack, but you also want a vector of pointers because of some API requirement, etc., Just create an array of the objects, then store the pointers. Be very mindful of the lifetime issues.

```
size_t const sz = 3;
A arr[sz] {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<A*> v;
v.reserve(sz);
for (auto& a : arr) v.push_back(&a);

someFunc(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** with your current program is that `A(i)` is a **prvalue** and hence its address using the `&` operator cannot be taken. This means that the following expression is invalid in your code:

```
//---------------------vvvvv----->invalid because A(i) is a prvalue
myCollection.push_back(&A(i));
```

---

You could instead use a `std::vector<A>` in addtion to `std::vector<A*>` as shown below:

```
std::vector<A> myVector;
myVector.reserve(10);
//-------^^^^^^^---------------->to avoid reallocations when capacity is not enough
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    myVector.emplace_back(i); 
//-----------^^^^^^^^^^^^------->use emplace_back to forward the argument i 
}

std::vector<A*> myPtrVector; 
myPtrVector.reserve(10);
for(auto&elem: myVector)
{
   myPtrVector.push_back(&elem);
}
```

Comment: That's rather dangerous. If `myVector` is ever changed and resizes all the pointers break.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Agreed. Just showing basic usage. According to the given requirements in the question.

Comment: Using smart pointers would be better and calling `make_shared` might count as avoiding `new` even though internally it's still used.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Note in the question OP says *"any way around this **without dynamic allocation**?"* and not *"without using `new`"*. Thus smart pointers cannot be used according to the given requirements of OP.

Comment: Don't forget that `std::vector` uses dynamic allocation. Just saying.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I think OP should keep this(that `std::vector` uses dynamical allocation) in mind.

Comment: vector could be replaced with array both times to solve that.